# linq to sql checking for null

Tags: linq-to-sql

my database field int_ParentId consist of a Null value . how would i check it for a null in this linq query . it is not working

```
  return _db.Categories.Where(m => m.int_ParentId==null);
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you mapped you `int_ParentId` database field to `int?` type (e.g. `<Column Name="int_ParentId" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" CanBeNull="true" />`)? If yes, both:

```
return _db.Categories.Where(m => m.int_ParentId == null);
```

and

```
return _db.Categories.Where(m => m.int_ParentId.HasValue);
```

should work.

Comment: perfect - exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 6):

This question is actually not easily answered given the lack of context you provide, though usually `_db.Categories.Where(m => m.int_ParentId.Equals(null));` does what you want.

There are a couple of discrepancies between the CTS (.NETs type system) and the SQL type system.

See [SQL-CLR Type Mismatches - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882669.aspx) and [Null Semantics - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882669.aspx) for the full reference.

Especially null will cause you headaches if you don't take enough care, since it has two completely different meanings in the respective typesystems. `NULL` in SQL means, "value absent, will match any comparison", whereas `null` in .NET means "no object, comparing against null will always yield false".

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use the object's `Equals` method:

```
return _db.Categories.Where(m => m.int_ParentId.Equals(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this query working in this scenario

```
YourContext db = new YourContext();
List<entity> list =  (from n in db.YourEntity
                     where n.FieldToCheck.Equals(null)
                     select n).ToList();
```

Hope it helps.