# Using ternary operator to check if null - null reference is not the same as null

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to use the ternary operator to check if a value is null and return one expression or the other. What I'm experiencing when incorporating this into a LINQ expression is that the Transact-SQL translation of the LINQ expression attempts to do a "column = null" rather than a "column IS NULL". I have reason to believe that this is because I'm doing the following:

```
mappedColumnName == (myVar == null ? null : myOtherVar)
```

Since it translates the following to columnName IS NULL in Transact-SQL:

```
mappedColumnName == null
```

Does anyone have any experience with this? I'd very much like to get this to work.

The entire LINQ expression:

```
(from MenuItem in menuContext.Menus
   where MenuItem.IsSysAdmin == (ClientID == 1 ? true : false)
   && MenuItem.IsActive == true
   && MenuItem.ParentMenuCode == (ActiveSubMenu==null?null:ActiveMenu)
   && MenuItem.ClientID == (UseClientMenu ? ClientID : 0)
   && MenuItem.EmployeeID == (UseEmployeeMenu ? EmployeeID : 0)
   orderby MenuItem.SortOrder, MenuItem.MenuName
   select MenuItem);
```

Comment: Can you please share your LINQ expression?

Comment: Of course. I've added it now.

Comment: Check this:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224339/linq-to-sql-checking-for-null][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224339/linq-to-sql-checking-for-null

Comment: Vitality: I'm not sure that'll work. I want to check if ParentMenuCode is null only if ActiveSubMenu is null, if it's not null I want to check if ParentMenuCode is equal to ActiveMenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never actually attempted to use ternary operators in linq although you could write it as:

```
(
    (myVar == null && mappedColumnName == null      ) ||
    (myVar != null && mappedColumnNmae == myOtherVar)
)
```

Comment: Thank you Jamie! This works, the workaround is also referenced at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097539/linq-where-column-null-reference-not-the-same-as-column-null

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use

```
mappedColumnName == (myVar == null ? DBNull.Value: myOtherVar)
```

instead?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(from MenuItem in menuContext.Menus
   where MenuItem.IsSysAdmin == ((ClientID == 1 )? true : false)
   && MenuItem.IsActive == true
   && MenuItem.ParentMenuCode == ( (ActiveSubMenu==null) ?null:ActiveMenu)
   && MenuItem.ClientID == (UseClientMenu ? ClientID : 0)
   && MenuItem.EmployeeID == (UseEmployeeMenu ? EmployeeID : 0)
   orderby MenuItem.SortOrder, MenuItem.MenuName
   select MenuItem);
```

Comment: Same result. The Transact-SQL translation of the ternary expression is a scalar method and Transact-SQL basically tries to perform columnName = null which will always fail.