# DateTime clause being ignored in Linq to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following LINQ query

```
db.Documents.Where(x => x.PublicationId == db.PublicationId &&
                                         x.CancellationDate == null)
```

The resulting SQL is ignoring the CancellationDate clause and timing out as a result.

I have tried the same query using other date fields all with the same result.

Is there something fundamental I am missing to execute SQL with date clauses using LINQ to SQL?

Edit:

The resulting SQL is essentially

```
   exec sp_executesql N'SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Document] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[PublicationId] = @p0',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier',@p0='47892838-9B52-4A4C-B4A2-8302A3FF5F22'
```

The SQL type of CancellationDate is nullable `DateTime` and the DBML property is Nullable, Server Data Type `DateTime` and Type `DateTime` (`System.DateTime`)

Also, if I change the LINQ to `x.CancellationDate < DateTime.Now` the resulting SQL also does not include this clause. `!x.CancellationDate.HasValue` has the same effect

Comment: Neither EF or LINQ to SQL or LINQ have any issues with dates. What is the resulting SQL statement? What is the field's type? Does it contain any values? Comparisons to NULL are always false in SQL which is why you need to use `IS NULL` instead of a comparison.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linq to sql checking for null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224339/linq-to-sql-checking-for-null)

Comment: Is `CancellationDate` a `DateTime?`? Have you tried using `CancellationDate.HasValue` instead of comparing to NULL? L2S has an annoying tendency to generate queries *only* for the operators it understands and using Linq to Objects to apply the rest. If `CancellationDate` is *not* DateTime?, L2S may decide it can't translate that clause and load everything in memory befory checking.

Comment: `System.DateTime` doesn't allow nulls. Which is why L2S ignores it in the query. That's *just* one reason why people are using EF instead of L2S by the way. The other is that it was meant to be a demonstration, not a fully featured ORM and never received significant updates since it first came out. You have to change the date fields to `DateTime?` if you want to check for nulls

Comment: Updated question with extra info. We are using EF6 elsewhere, just not in this particular project

Comment: Im having the same issue with any date time clause, not just null checks

Comment: Does the table column exist? Is the mapping OK? Try creating a new, minimal project that reproduces this behaviour. Just a single class with a name and date for example

Comment: The column exists. The resulting record after a FirstOrDefault is applied has its cancellation date updated successfully, so there's no issue with the mapping.

Comment: Is this a standalone query or are you building a query over various steps? One thing that irritates me, is the `db.PublicationId`. _db_ is your DataContext, right? Why ist the Id you are filtering by is stored in the DataContext?